# Where can I get custom-fitted earplugs in Bangkok?

Tags: health, thailand, shopping, sleeping, bangkok

I use [custom-fitted earplugs](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/22370/2589) sometimes when in transportation, e.g. airplane or sleeper train. Where can I get custom-fitted earplugs in Bangkok?

---

Note to close voters: the question is not about "price-shopping for specific goods or services" at all. It is about buying a specific product in a specific place, which is 100% on topic, e.g. see the 200+ questions in [shopping](/questions/tagged/shopping).

Comment: Most audiologists will do ear molds and make custom fitted plugs. This typically not cheap, but Thailand may still be affordable. There are plenty of hearing aids in Thailand, so there are probably plenty of audiologists in Bangkok proper. Alternatives: there are thermo-form plugs that you can mold yourself and using active noise cancelling plugs, which typically do a much better job that passive ones, even with a few gap and non-perfect fits.

Comment: Or use wax plugs, which you shape for every use.

Comment: Wax plugs often create deposits in the ear canal that can build up over time. That's why most mold-able plugs these days are foam, but they don't seal very well

Comment: Remember, be nice. Question is on topic, but got delete by lack of answers, first time around

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some pointers left as comments:

> Most audiologists will do ear molds and make custom fitted plugs. This typically not cheap, but Thailand may still be affordable. There are plenty of hearing aids in Thailand, so there are probably plenty of audiologists in Bangkok proper. Alternatives: there are thermo-form plugs that you can mold yourself and using active noise cancelling plugs, which typically do a much better job that passive ones, even with a few gap and non-perfect fits. – [Hilmar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13971/hilmar) [14 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159261/where-can-i-get-custom-fitted-earplugs-in-bangkok?noredirect=1#comment399318_159261)

> I got my custom fitted earplugs from an optician who in my country mostly do hearing aids as well. – [Willeke**♦**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) [Jul 17 at 4:23](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158361/where-can-i-get-custom-fitted-earplugs-in-bangkok#comment395994_158361)

> Check out the local gun clubs. At least in the US during large matches or tournaments there are vendors selling custom molded earplugs. – [gamma_sponge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/85314/gamma-sponge) [Jul 17 at 20:23](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158361/where-can-i-get-custom-fitted-earplugs-in-bangkok#comment396032_158361)